# How to have integer subtract from a string in python?

Tags: python, string, integer, chatbot

I'm currently working on a chatbot from scratch as an assignment for my intro to python class. In my assignment I need to have at least one "mathematical component". I cant seem to find out how to have my input integer subtract from a string.

Attached is a screen shot, My goal is to have them input how many days a week they cook at home and have that subtract from 7 automatically.

```
print('Hello! What is your name? ')
my_name = input ()
print('Nice to meet you ' + my_name)
print('So, ' + my_name + ' What is your favorite veggie?')
favorite_veggie = input ()
print('Thats nuts! ' +favorite_veggie + ' is mine too!')
print('How many days a week do you have cook at home? ')
day = input ()
print('So what do you do the other ' + ????? 'days?')
```

Comment: Do `input('Hello! What is your name? ')`, `input('So, ' + my_name + ' What is your favorite veggie?')` and `input('How many days a week do you have cook at home? ')` for better code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for this

```
day = input()
required_days = 7 - int(day)
print('So what do you do the other ' + str(required_days) + ' days?')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
day = int(input())
print('So what do you do the other', 7-day, 'days?')
```

Answer (score 0):

You may convert the result of the `input` to `int`, then do the substraction. Also `input("")` accepts a string as parameter, that will be shown in front of the prompt area, that makes better code

```
my_name = input('Hello! What is your name? ')
print('Nice to meet you ' + my_name)

favorite_veggie = input('So, ' + my_name + ' What is your favorite veggie?')
print('Thats nuts! ' + favorite_veggie + ' is mine too!')

day = int(input('How many days a week do you have cook at home? '))
non_work_day = 7 - day
what_do = input('So what do you do the other ' + str(non_work_day) + 'days?')
```